# Using VNC client to access local QEMU VM

Tags: vnc, qemu

I have installed Debian in a QEMU VM and am currently using the default QEMU Manager as the main display, since QEMU allows VNC as the main display.

I have a VNC client installed on my PC; can I view the VM using VNC? If yes, how?